# Row/column swap 0-1 matrix to get a lower-triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Suppose there is an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ whose entries are 0 and 1, and exactly $2n-1$ many entries are 1's.

I am wondering if we can get a lower-triangular matrix from $M$ by only allowing to swap rows and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for example when $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.